# Get website information with regex and import it to listbox

Tags: c#, io

When I start the process, I get in the listbox ":" and 68,000 hits
I have never used WebRequest this is the first time, so I had no idea.

My regex and theoretically good it recovers 2 groups, the ip and the port
besides I have a question, since the port are between 2/5 digits that follow. that can be a problem? because ip are a suites of 2/3 digits?

And so after I make a loop so that it recovers everything, and that it puts the result in the listbox1 by separating the ip and the port by ":".

If someone have an answer!

Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to use an HTML parser, such as [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```
string Url = "https://www.us-proxy.org/";
        WebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Url));
        WebResponse wResp = wReq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

        Regex Filtrer = new Regex("^([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}) ([0-9]{2,5})$");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            Match matches = Filtrer.Match(str);
            listBox1.Items.Add(matches.Groups[1].Value +":"+ matches.Groups[2].Value);                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
string Url = "https://www.us-proxy.org/";
        WebRequest wReq = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(Url));
        WebResponse wResp = wReq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream());
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = str.Split('\n');

        Regex Filtrer = new Regex("^([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})([0-9]{2,5})$");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {               
            Match matches = Filtrer.Match(lines[i]);
            listBox1.Items.Add(matches.Groups[1].Value + ":" + matches.Groups[2].Value);
        }
```

But, I got always ":" is the listbox.
And I got 7 items in the listbox, but I try to parse 20items in the url.